# databricks parsing JSON using spark SQL

Tags: json, parsing, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I'm trying to parse JSON using spark SQL in databricks. I'm more familiar with SQL than spark. Any recommendations how to parse this JSON?

```json
{
    "messageTimestamp": "2023-05-05T10:40:44.692-04:00",
    "siteReference": "FL99,FL5,FL55",
    "updateCount": 2,
    "updates": [
        {
            "eventTimestamp": "2023-05-05T10:40:44.692-04:00",
            "spotReference": "AA18_FL5",
            "spotInfo": {
                "vehicleSpot": {
                    "familyType": "VEHICLE_SPOT",
                    "type": "DockDoor",
                    "externalReference": "AA18_FL5",
                    "state": "Busy",
                    "displayState": "Busy",
                    "fields": {
                        "c3FieldStrings": [
                            {
                                "externalReference": "4095",
                                "name": "Blocking Spot"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "Disabled",
                                "name": "Disabled",
                                "value": "false"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "WorkflowVehicleSpot",
                                "name": "Spot",
                                "value": "AA18_FL5"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "WorkflowVMT",
                                "name": "WorkflowVMT"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "SPOT_ExternalReference",
                                "name": "External Reference",
                                "value": "AA18_FL5"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "4094",
                                "name": "Blocked By Spot"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "SPOT_SubWarehouse",
                                "name": "Sub Warehouse",
                                "value": "FL5_RECV"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "SPOT_Site",
                                "name": "Site",
                                "value": "FL99,FL5,FL55"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "OriginRestriction",
                                "name": "Origin Restriction",
                                "value": "FL5"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "ZonePathInfo",
                                "name": "Zone Path Info",
                                "value": "AA18"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "UnderReviewedBy",
                                "name": "Under Reviewed By"
                            }
                        ],
                        "c3FieldIntegers": [
                            {
                                "externalReference": "Workflow",
                                "name": "Workflow",
                                "value": 3637
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "SPOT_VehicleZoneType",
                                "name": "Vehicle Zone Type"
                            }
                        ],
                        "c3FieldDecimals": [],
                        "c3FieldDateTimes": [
                            {
                                "externalReference": "DisabledTimestamp",
                                "name": "Disabled Timestamp"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "LockedTimestamp",
                                "name": "Locked Timestamp",
                                "value": "2023-05-03T08:24:03.360-04:00"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "OutgoingTimestamp",
                                "name": "Outgoing Timestamp",
                                "value": "2023-05-03T11:20:48.227-04:00"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "BusyTimestamp",
                                "name": "Busy Timestamp",
                                "value": "2023-05-05T10:40:43.887-04:00"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "ConfirmedDate",
                                "name": "Confirmed Date",
                                "value": "2023-05-05T10:40:43.953-04:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "vehicleData": {
                    "familyType": "VEHICLE_DATA",
                    "type": "Vehicle",
                    "externalReference": "ONEY-TLLU4069090",
                    "state": "InUse",
                    "displayState": "Waiting for Errand",
                    "fields": {
                        "c3FieldStrings": [
                            {
                                "externalReference": "Vendor",
                                "name": "Vendor"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "WorkflowVehicleSpot",
                                "name": "WorkflowVehicleSpot",
                                "value": "AA18_FL5"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "WorkflowWorkerExecution",
                                "name": "WorkflowWorkerExecution"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "FaultSummary",
                                "name": "Fault Summary"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "WorkflowReservation",
                                "name": "WorkflowReservation",
                                "value": "13227269"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "ChassisNumber",
                                "name": "Chassis #"
                            }
                        ],
                        "c3FieldIntegers": [
                            {
                                "externalReference": "VehicleZoneType",
                                "name": "Vehicle Zone Type"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "Workflow",
                                "name": "Workflow",
                                "value": 8203
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "FTX",
                                "name": "FTX",
                                "value": 7
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "FaultCode",
                                "name": "Fault Code"
                            }
                        ],
                        "c3FieldDecimals": [],
                        "c3FieldDateTimes": [
                            {
                                "externalReference": "ArrivalTime",
                                "name": "Arrival Time",
                                "value": "2023-04-27T10:55:42.800-04:00"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "DepartureTime",
                                "name": "Departure Time"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "PMDate",
                                "name": "PM Date"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "CreatedTimestamp",
                                "name": "Created Timestamp",
                                "value": "2023-04-27T10:55:06.750-04:00"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "AnnualInspectionDate",
                                "name": "Annual Inspection Date"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "vehicleExecution": {
                    "familyType": "VEHICLE_EXECUTION",
                    "type": "Delivery",
                    "externalReference": "1667328",
                    "state": "WaitingforErrand",
                    "displayState": "Waiting for Errand",
                    "fields": {
                        "c3FieldStrings": [
                            {
                                "externalReference": "WorkflowVehicleSpot",
                                "name": "Spot",
                                "value": "AA18_FL5"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "CreatedAtGate",
                                "name": "Created at Gate",
                                "value": "false"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "WorkflowVMT",
                                "name": "WorkflowVMT"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "ExternalReference",
                                "name": "External Reference",
                                "value": "1667328"
                            }
                        ],
                        "c3FieldIntegers": [
                            {
                                "externalReference": "Workflow",
                                "name": "Workflow",
                                "value": 173227
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "4112",
                                "name": "ErrandSequence"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "ErrandType",
                                "name": "Errand Type"
                            }
                        ],
                        "c3FieldDecimals": [],
                        "c3FieldDateTimes": [
                            {
                                "externalReference": "Ready for DepartureTimestamp",
                                "name": "Ready for Departure Timestamp"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "Doing ErrandTimestamp",
                                "name": "Doing Errand Timestamp"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "Waiting for ErrandTimestamp",
                                "name": "Waiting for Errand Timestamp",
                                "value": "2023-04-27T11:00:51.233-04:00"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "DepartureTime",
                                "name": "Departure Time"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "eventTimestamp": "2023-05-05T10:40:44.692-04:00",
            "spotReference": "FL99_A-025",
            "spotInfo": {
                "vehicleSpot": {
                    "familyType": "VEHICLE_SPOT",
                    "type": "Parking",
                    "externalReference": "FL99_A-025",
                    "state": "Available",
                    "displayState": "Available",
                    "fields": {
                        "c3FieldStrings": [
                            {
                                "externalReference": "4095",
                                "name": "Blocking Spot"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "Disabled",
                                "name": "Disabled",
                                "value": "false"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "WorkflowVehicleSpot",
                                "name": "Spot",
                                "value": "FL99_A-025"
                            }
                        ],
                        "c3FieldIntegers": [
                            {
                                "externalReference": "Workflow",
                                "name": "Workflow",
                                "value": 3723
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "SPOT_VehicleZoneType",
                                "name": "Vehicle Zone Type"
                            }
                        ],
                        "c3FieldDecimals": [],
                        "c3FieldDateTimes": [
                            {
                                "externalReference": "DisabledTimestamp",
                                "name": "Disabled Timestamp"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "LockedTimestamp",
                                "name": "Locked Timestamp"
                            },
                            {
                                "externalReference": "OutgoingTimestamp",
                                "name": "Outgoing Timestamp",
                                "value": "2023-05-03T17:05:23.363-04:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please see the attachment

Comment: How do you get this JSON - is it loaded from files? Or from Kafka, etc.?

Comment: It's a json file our vendor is sending every hour. We get this in Azure blob storage now I have to read this , parse and load it to Databricks.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of achieving this:

- The simplest way to achieve this using SQL only is to use `COPY INTO` SQL command ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-copy-into.html), [tutorial](https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/copy-into/index.html)) that can read files from the cloud storage, parse it according to the specified file format, and then you can apply your transformations.  The actual implementation would depend on if you want to ingest all data vs. extracting only specific fields, etc.  This command provides incremental data ingestion, without re-ingesting the already processed data. Something like this:

```sql
COPY INTO table_name
 FROM 'abfss://container@storage.dfs.core.windows.net/path'
 FILEFORMAT = JSON
```

- You can implement [Delta Live tables pipelines using SQL](https://docs.databricks.com/delta-live-tables/tutorial-sql.html) as well - it's [natively supporting Databricks Auto Loader](https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/auto-loader/dlt.html) that provides efficient way of ingesting the data from the cloud storage.
- You can also ingest this data as plain text, and then use JSON expressions to extract necessary fields, although it could be quite tedious when you have a very complex JSON.